# relationship between $L^p$ convergence and a.s. convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

$X_n$ are r.v. which convergent  to $X$ a.s.(1)

and $\sup_n\mathbb E[|X_n|]<\infty$ (2)

there is a counterexample that $X_n$ do not convergent to $X$ in $L^1$:$n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$

But when (2) is replaced by $\sup_n\mathbb E[|X_n|^p]<\infty$

Could we get conclusion that $X_n$ convergent to $X$ in $L^p$?($p>1$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New counterexample: $n^{1/p}\chi_{[0,1/n]}$